# prop.table() in R on a list of tables

Tags: r, list, transition

I have several tables with same format and I want to run `prop.table` on all of those tables. How can I run `prop.table` on a list of tables? By saying "list of tables" I mean vector of table names.

my_table <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 35L, 274L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 42L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 3L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 5L, 168L, 140L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 60L, 580L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 110L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 20L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 20L, 246L, 1148L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 837L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 31L, 65L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(13L, 19L), .Dimnames = structure(list( c("1029", "1031", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "528", "9"), c("0", "1029", "1031", "133", "17", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "5", "528", "529", "67", "9")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")

my_table2 <- structure(c(68L, 108L, 27L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 0L, 39L, 641L, 5213L, 161L, 3L, 21L, 182L, 40L, 23L, 19L, 13L, 27L, 25L, 12L, 32L, 2207L, 476L, 15L, 2L, 63L, 19L, 8L, 44L, 708L, 139L, 54L, 16L, 65L, 404L, 116L, 88L, 122L, 35L, 59L, 59L, 1L, 67L, 41L, 466L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 429L, 94L, 2L, 0L, 49L, 48L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 19L, 0L, 4L, 28L, 12L, 1026L, 193L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 19L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 24L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 24L, 9L, 22L, 604L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 137L, 15L, 121L, 35L, 5L, 8L, 187L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 4L, 34L, 16L, 6L, 48L, 68L, 25L, 21L, 1L, 72L, 70L, 2L, 9L, 33L, 20L, 10L, 2L, 26L, 113L, 1L, 0L, 30L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 24L, 21L, 7L, 26L, 8L, 6L, 100L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 17L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 96L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 87L, 220L, 11L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 0L, 11L, 1703L, 538L, 31L, 5L, 32L, 126L, 21L, 25L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 22L, 4L, 46L, 87L, 101L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 26L, 760L, 3071L, 59L, 5L, 22L, 161L, 26L, 11L, 18L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 617L, 27L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 11L, 25L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 59L, 97L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 95L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 53L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 43L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 0L, 2L, 169L, 306L, 5L, 3L, 19L, 27L, 7L, 31L, 742L, 170L, 53L, 7L, 36L, 1768L, 291L, 31L, 53L, 22L, 32L, 43L, 1L, 17L, 102L, 288L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 152L, 36L, 16L, 2L, 32L, 654L, 394L, 24L, 83L, 13L, 16L, 30L, 1L, 15L, 57L, 34L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 23L, 34L, 211L, 15L, 6L, 19L, 11L, 1L, 35L, 343L, 187L, 5L, 2L, 19L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 80L, 34L, 45L, 9L, 77L, 213L, 276L, 28L, 241L, 37L, 18L, 84L, 2L, 20L, 31L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 15L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 22L, 29L, 24L, 1L, 13L, 18L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 3L, 35L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 37L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 29L, 17L, 20L, 4L, 0L, 213L, 11L, 2L, 7L, 112L, 78L, 4L, 6L, 129L, 49L, 3L, 0L, 62L, 24L, 31L, 5L, 45L, 75L, 62L, 20L, 126L, 31L, 23L, 170L, 2L, 14L, 20L, 4L, 32L, 37L, 15L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 11L, 22L, 563L, 13L, 23L, 9L, 222L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 39L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1053L), .Dim = 22:23, .Dimnames = structure(list( c("1029", "1031", "12", "13", "133", "17", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "5", "528", "529", "65", "67", "7", "9"), c("0", "1029", "1031", "12", "13", "133", "17", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "5", "528", "529", "65", "67", "7", "9")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")

list <- list(c("my_table", "my_table2"))

Comment: The data shown is not a list of tables.  It is a single table.  If ithe question is about a list of tables please show  such.

Comment: Yes, it is not a list of tables, but an example of those tables. All of them are the same structure and format.

Comment: The additional structure is not a list of tables. It is a list containing a character vector presumably of names of variables such that each such variable exists in your workspace and contains a table.  Is that what you meant?  If so please provide a complete minimal reproducible example (not just a fragment) that can be used by those wishing to answer the question.  See the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Hi, updated the question. Hope that it will make more clear.

Comment: OK, but note that it is still not a lisit of table names. It is a list  containing a single character vector of table names.  A list of table names would be list <- list("my_table", "my_table2") and actually it would be sufficient to have a character vector of table names tabnames <- c("my_table", "my_table2")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `LIST` is your list of tables:

```
prop.list <-lapply(LIST,function(x){
              prop.table(x)
            })
```

Comment: The manual says *prop.table is an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility*. So it might be better to call it now `proportions`.

Comment: Thank you, I made a real list (not a vector of table names which I had previously) of all tables and used your approach, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Edited for a more complete example using both example tables and using both `prop.table` and `proportions`...

```r
library(purrr)
my_table <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 35L, 274L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 42L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 3L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 5L, 168L, 140L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 60L, 580L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 110L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 20L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 20L, 246L, 1148L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 837L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 31L, 65L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(13L, 19L), .Dimnames = structure(list( c("1029", "1031", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "528", "9"), c("0", "1029", "1031", "133", "17", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "5", "528", "529", "67", "9")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
my_table2 <- structure(c(68L, 108L, 27L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 0L, 39L, 641L, 5213L, 161L, 3L, 21L, 182L, 40L, 23L, 19L, 13L, 27L, 25L, 12L, 32L, 2207L, 476L, 15L, 2L, 63L, 19L, 8L, 44L, 708L, 139L, 54L, 16L, 65L, 404L, 116L, 88L, 122L, 35L, 59L, 59L, 1L, 67L, 41L, 466L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 429L, 94L, 2L, 0L, 49L, 48L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 19L, 0L, 4L, 28L, 12L, 1026L, 193L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 19L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 24L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 24L, 9L, 22L, 604L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 137L, 15L, 121L, 35L, 5L, 8L, 187L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 4L, 34L, 16L, 6L, 48L, 68L, 25L, 21L, 1L, 72L, 70L, 2L, 9L, 33L, 20L, 10L, 2L, 26L, 113L, 1L, 0L, 30L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 24L, 21L, 7L, 26L, 8L, 6L, 100L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 17L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 96L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 87L, 220L, 11L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 0L, 11L, 1703L, 538L, 31L, 5L, 32L, 126L, 21L, 25L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 22L, 4L, 46L, 87L, 101L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 26L, 760L, 3071L, 59L, 5L, 22L, 161L, 26L, 11L, 18L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 2L, 20L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 617L, 27L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 11L, 25L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 59L, 97L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 95L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 53L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 43L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 0L, 2L, 169L, 306L, 5L, 3L, 19L, 27L, 7L, 31L, 742L, 170L, 53L, 7L, 36L, 1768L, 291L, 31L, 53L, 22L, 32L, 43L, 1L, 17L, 102L, 288L, 2L, 2L, 24L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 152L, 36L, 16L, 2L, 32L, 654L, 394L, 24L, 83L, 13L, 16L, 30L, 1L, 15L, 57L, 34L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 23L, 34L, 211L, 15L, 6L, 19L, 11L, 1L, 35L, 343L, 187L, 5L, 2L, 19L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 80L, 34L, 45L, 9L, 77L, 213L, 276L, 28L, 241L, 37L, 18L, 84L, 2L, 20L, 31L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 15L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 22L, 29L, 24L, 1L, 13L, 18L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 3L, 35L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 37L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 29L, 17L, 20L, 4L, 0L, 213L, 11L, 2L, 7L, 112L, 78L, 4L, 6L, 129L, 49L, 3L, 0L, 62L, 24L, 31L, 5L, 45L, 75L, 62L, 20L, 126L, 31L, 23L, 170L, 2L, 14L, 20L, 4L, 32L, 37L, 15L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 11L, 22L, 563L, 13L, 23L, 9L, 222L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 39L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1053L), .Dim = 22:23, .Dimnames = structure(list( c("1029", "1031", "12", "13", "133", "17", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "5", "528", "529", "65", "67", "7", "9"), c("0", "1029", "1031", "12", "13", "133", "17", "2056", "2060", "2061", "256", "258", "259", "265", "4114", "4115", "5", "528", "529", "65", "67", "7", "9")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table") 
my_list_of_tables <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
my_list_of_tables[[1]] <- my_table
my_list_of_tables[[2]] <- my_table2
# my_list_of_tables

my_list_of_proptables <- purrr::map(my_list_of_tables, proportions)
my_list_of_proptables2 <- purrr::map(my_list_of_tables, prop.table)
all.equal(my_list_of_proptables, my_list_of_proptables2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: ```Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'proportions' not found```

Comment: try `prop.table` then?  What version of `r`

Comment: Hi, by saying "list of tables" I mean a character vector with table names, which I have in my environment list <- list(c("my_table", "my_table2")). And R version 3.5.1. But your approach works if I create real list of tables, thanks.

Comment: Ah okay.  Misunderstood what you meant